# How can i use comparator in aggrid if i am using external json file for columndefs,i need to use comparator for only one column?

Tags: ag-grid-react

I have a json file in which i have all columns name and as aggrid doesnt providing sorting for datetime so want to use custom sorting with aggrid comparator,but as it is a external json file so can anyone help me how to use comparator for only that specific column.i tried to add dynamically that particular column with push before using the json file in the columndefs but it is not working.